# How to get the RequestParam name in ConstraintViolationException when field validation fails in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

Is there a way to retrieve the RequestParam name (not the field variable name) in springboot validation?

For example

```
@GetMapping(value = "/abc")
public Response getABC(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(name = user_number, defaultValue = "1") @Positive Integer number) {

// other code logic

}
```

Here when user_number validation fails, is there a way to capture the RequestParam name (user_number) in ConstraintViolationException and display it in the error message? I know there is PropertyPath from which the field name can be extracted but I am looking to fetch the RequestParam name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement org.springframework.validation.Validator interface with the supports and validate methods.

A detailed tutorial on this is available [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators).

Comment: Implement a custom validator for all the field types?

Comment: Yes, for all the request parameters in ideal scenario. Or you can pick and choose fields as per your need.